# How to build my own project on github which is aligned with a upstream repro

Tags: github

I want to build a project on github which could align with other's project.
How to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another remote repo to your current working repository with:

`git remote add <name> <url>`

then you can list it with

`git remote -v`

There foreyou can push to/pull from it

`git push <new_remote_name>`

Comment: If that solved your question please upvote/mark the question as answered :)